# Apache: Configuration for main site and subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, subdomain

I want to setup an specific environment for my hostings, but don't know what's the best approach.

I want have a domain called example.com.

```
* The www. should contain the main website (hosting site)
* every subdomain ex. customer1.example.com needs to be redirected to a subfolder
```

I don't know what is the best approach. Having an virtualhost for every customer or having one virtualhost for the service and redirect using mod_rewrite? I'm currently setting up this environment local, so if you have an good idea plase don't forget to mention the hosts file.

Everything should be automatically generated and on the fly included.

Kind regards, Ward

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

Comment: are there other options instead putting it in database ?

Comment: mod_vhost_alias doesn't use any database.